# Manual ordering of color palette when using discrete_scale to generate custom ggplot2 scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-palette

I have created a custom ggplot2 fill/colour scale as a wrapper around `discrete_scale`, the only parameter in the ggplot2 scale function that wraps around `discrete_scale` is `shade`. I actually have 4 different color palettes that are chosen based on this parameter: light, midtone, dark, outline.

The problem I'm facing is that when I call these different shades within the scale wrapper functions (fill and colour), the order of these colors vary. How can I ensure a consistent order?

```
palette_light_custom <- c("#FF61c3", "#53c1e8", "#82FF73", "#FFFA5C", "#FFA200", "#FF6D5C", "#C478FF", "#C478FF", "#C478FF")
palette_midtone_custom <- c("#f84eb7", "#f3413a", "#f48c00", "#fffa5c", "#56dc5b", "#219ed4", "#b86ef4", "#b86ef4", "#b86ef4")
palette_dark_custom <- c("#e0008a", "#eb0008", "#f48c00", "#fffa5c", "#15a736", "#0085cf", "#8745c6", "#8745c6", "#8745c6")
palette_outline_custom <- c("#a30059", "#005ba1", "#6729a7", "#FFFA5C", "#FFA200", "#FF6D5C", "#C478FF", "#C478FF", "#C478FF")

pal_light <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_light_custom) }
pal_midtone <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_midtone_custom) }
pal_dark <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_dark_custom) }
pal_outline <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_outline_custom) }

scale_colour_custom <- function(shade, ...) { 
  if (shade == "light") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_light_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "midtone") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_midtone_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "dark") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_dark_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "outline") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_outline_custom(), ...) 
  } else {
    stop("Incorrect or missing shade parameter in scale_color_custom()")
  }
}

scale_color_custom <- scale_colour_custom

scale_fill_custom <- function(shade, ...) { 
  if (shade == "light") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_light_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "midtone") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_midtone_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "dark") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_dark_custom(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "outline") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_outline_custom(), ...) 
  } else {
    stop("Incorrect or missing shade parameter in scale_color_custom()")
  }
}

ggplot(data=iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           color = Species, 
           fill = Spcies)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  scale_colour_custom("outline") +
  scale_fill_custom("midtone") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Notice in the image that the fill and colour do not line up. How can I enforce `discrete_scale()` to choose the order by which the color palette is specified?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Thanks for the extra detail in your comments; does this solve your problem?

```
library(tidyverse)
palette_light_custom <- c("#FF61c3", "#FF6D5C", "#FFA200", "#FFFA5C", "#82FF73", "#53c1e8", "#C478FF", "#C478FF", "#C478FF")
palette_midtone_custom <- c("#f84eb7", "#f3413a", "#f48c00", "#fffa5c", "#56dc5b", "#219ed4", "#b86ef4", "#b86ef4", "#b86ef4")
palette_dark_custom <- c("#e0008a", "#eb0008", "#d97d00", "#fffa5c", "#15a736", "#0085cf", "#8745c6", "#8745c6", "#8745c6")
palette_outline_custom <- c("#ad006b", "#b50006", "#c26f00", "#f7f000", "#006e19", "#005ba1", "#6729a7", "#6729a7", "#6729a7")

scales::show_col(palette_light_custom)
scales::show_col(palette_midtone_custom)
scales::show_col(palette_dark_custom)
scales::show_col(palette_outline_custom)

pal_light <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_light_custom) }
pal_midtone <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_midtone_custom) }
pal_dark <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_dark_custom) }
pal_outline <- function() { scales::manual_pal(palette_outline_custom) }

scale_colour_custom <- function(shade, ...) { 
  if (shade == "light") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_light(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "midtone") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_midtone(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "dark") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_dark(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "outline") {
    discrete_scale("colour", "custom", pal_outline(), ...) 
  } else {
    stop("Incorrect or missing shade parameter in scale_color_custom()")
  }
}

scale_fill_custom <- function(shade, ...) { 
  if (shade == "light") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_light(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "midtone") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_midtone(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "dark") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_dark(), ...) 
  } else if (shade == "outline") {
    discrete_scale("fill", "custom", pal_outline(), ...) 
  } else {
    stop("Incorrect or missing shade parameter in scale_color_custom()")
  }
}

ggplot(data=iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           color = Species, 
           fill = Species)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  scale_colour_custom("outline") +
  scale_fill_custom("light") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: example_light.png]

```
ggplot(data=iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           color = Species, 
           fill = Species)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  scale_colour_custom("outline") +
  scale_fill_custom("midtone") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: example_midtone.png]

```
ggplot(data=iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           color = Species, 
           fill = Species)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  scale_colour_custom("outline") +
  scale_fill_custom("dark") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: example_dark.png]

Comment: Thanks but this is still incorrect, even in your examples posted, the colors do not line up.

Comment: If you want them to be the same, why can't you use the same palette: `scale_colour_custom("midtone") + scale_fill_custom("midtone")` (i.e. get rid of 'outline' altogether)?

Comment: outline is a different set of colors -darker shades of the same base color. This is all obvious from the code above...